# Windows Service crashes

Tags: windows, windows-services, crash

I have a windows service running on **Windows Server 2003**. The service crashes ocassionlly. I tried analysis error through DebugDiag and got following information. Can anyone help me to understand the problem. The service uses GSM libaray for SMS service.

**Error:**

```
  In EnfieldSMSService__PID__1764__Date__01_21_2011__Time_09_34_31AM__554__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.
 dmp the assembly instruction at 0x00bb29d1 which does not correspond to any
 known native module in the process has caused an access violation exception
 (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000008 on thread 10
 Report for
 >EnfieldSMSService__PID__1764__Date__01_21_2011__Time_09_34_31AM__554__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.
 dmp
 Type of Analysis Performed   Crash Analysis 
 Machine Name   REALTRACSERVER 
 Operating System   Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 
 Number Of Processors   4 
 Process ID   1764 
 Process Image   C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\EnfieldSMSSetUp\
 EnfieldSMSService.exe 
 System Up-Time   7 day(s) 18:30:55 
 Process Up-Time   00:05:24 
 Thread 10 - System ID 3632
 Entry point   mscorwks!CreateApplicationContext+bbef 
 Create time   1/21/2011 9:34:31 AM 
 Time spent in user mode   0 Days 0:0:0.0 
 Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 0:0:0.0 
 Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3   Source 
 0x00bb29d1     01041e54     00b8f8c4     792d6cf6    
 0x00bb11c7     01041ee0     00b8f8d8     792e019f    
 mscorlib_ni+216cf6     00b8f91c     01041ee0     01041eac    
 mscorlib_ni+22019f     01041eac     00000000     001df020    
 mscorlib_ni+216c74     00000217     7c82b02a     00b8f980    
 mscorwks+1b4c     00b8f9d0     00000000     00b8f9a0    
 mscorwks!DllUnregisterServerInternal+6195     00b8f9d0     00000000
 00b8f9a0    
 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+2e95     7924290c     00b8fc14     00b8fb4c    
 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+2ec8     7924290c     00b8fc14     00b8fb4c    
 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+2ee6     00b8fb4c     95f5cb6e     001df020    
 mscorwks!CorExitProcess+1e4d     00b8fe50     00000000     00000000    
 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4df3     00b8fdc4     00b8fd70     79f7759b    
 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4d8f     00b8fdc4     95f5ca02     00000000    
 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4cb5     00b8fdc4     00000001     00000000    
 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4e41     00000001     79f3d6e9     00b8fe50    
 mscorwks!CorExitProcess+1c1e     00000001     79f3d6e9     00b8fe50    
 mscorwks!CorExitProcess+1cf8     001e2f68     00000001     00000001    
 mscorwks!CreateApplicationContext+bc35     0019cf88     00000000     00000000
 kernel32!GetModuleHandleA+df     79f91fcf     0019cf88     00000000    
 Detailed stack corruption analysis for thread 10
 Call stack with StackWalk
 Index Return Address 
 1 0x00bb29d1 
 2 0x00bb11c7 
 3 mscorlib_ni+216cf6 
 4 mscorlib_ni+22019f 
 5 mscorlib_ni+216c74 
 6 mscorwks+1b4c 
 7 mscorwks!DllUnregisterServerInternal+6195 
 8 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+2e95 
 9 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+2ec8 
 10 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+2ee6 
 11 mscorwks!CorExitProcess+1e4d 
 12 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4df3 
 13 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4d8f 
 14 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4cb5 
 15 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4e41 
 16 mscorwks!CorExitProcess+1c1e 
 17 mscorwks!CorExitProcess+1cf8 
 18 mscorwks!CreateApplicationContext+bc35 
 19 kernel32!GetModuleHandleA+df 
 Call stack - Heuristic
 Index Stack Address Child EBP Return Address Destination 
 1 0x00000000 0x00b8f8ac 0x00bb29d1 0x00000000 
 2 0x00b8f8b0 0x00b8f8b8 0x00bb11c7 0x00bb2940 
 3 0x00b8f8bc 0x00b8f8c4 mscorlib_ni+216cf6 0x00000000 
 4 0x00b8f8c8 0x00b8f8d8 mscorlib_ni+22019f 0x00000000 
 5 0x00b8f8dc 0x00b8f8f0 mscorlib_ni+216c74 mscorlib_ni+220130 
 6 0x00b8f8f4 0x00b8f900 mscorwks+1b4c 0x00000000 
 7 0x00b8f904 0x00b8f980 mscorwks!DllUnregisterServerInternal+6195
 mscorwks+1b19 
 8 0x00b8f984 0x00b8fab8 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+2e95 mscorwks!
 DllUnregisterServerInternal+60f6 
 9 0x00b8fabc 0x00b8fad4 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+2ec8 mscorwks!
 CoUninitializeEE+2d3b 
 10 0x00b8fad8 0x00b8faec mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+2ee6 mscorwks!
 CoUninitializeEE+2ea9 
 11 0x00b8faf0 0x00b8fcd4 mscorwks!CorExitProcess+1e4d mscorwks!
 CoUninitializeEE+2ecc 
 12 0x00b8fcd8 0x00b8fce8 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4df3 0x00000000 
 13 0x00b8fcec 0x00b8fd7c mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4d8f mscorwks!
 CoUninitializeEE+4dc8 
 14 0x00b8fd80 0x00b8fdb8 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4cb5 mscorwks!
 CoUninitializeEE+4ce0 
 15 0x00b8fdbc 0x00b8fde0 mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+4e41 mscorwks!
      CoUninitializeEE+4c90 
      16 0x00b8fde4 0x00b8fdf8 mscorwks!CorExitProcess+1c1e mscorwks!
      CoUninitializeEE+4e1c 
      17 0x00b8fdfc 0x00b8fe94 mscorwks!CorExitProcess+1cf8 mscorwks!
      CorExitProcess+1c0b 
      18 0x00b8fe98 0x00b8ffb8 mscorwks!CreateApplicationContext+bc35 0x00000000 
      19 0x00b8ffbc 0x00b8ffec kernel32!GetModuleHandleA+df 0x00000000 
      792d6cf4 ffd0            call    eax
      792e019d ffd0            call    eax
      792d6c6f e8bc940000      call    mscorlib_ni+0x220130 (792e0130)
      79e71b49 ff5518          call    dword ptr [ebp+18h]
      79e821ac e868f9feff      call    mscorwks+0x1b19 (79e71b19)
      79e964fc e811bcfeff      call    mscorwks!DllUnregisterServerInternal+0x60f6
      (79e82112)
      79e9652f e873feffff      call    mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+0x2d3b (79e963a7)
      79e9654d e8c3ffffff      call    mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+0x2ea9 (79e96515)
      79f3d7fe e8358df5ff      call    mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+0x2ecc (79e96538)
      79e9845c ff560c          call    dword ptr [esi+0Ch]
      79e983f6 e839000000      call    mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+0x4dc8 (79e98434)
      79e9831c e82b000000      call    mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+0x4ce0 (79e9834c)
      79e984a8 e84ffeffff      call    mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+0x4c90 (79e982fc)
      79f3d5cf e8b4aef5ff      call    mscorwks!CoUninitializeEE+0x4e1c (79e98488)
      79f3d6a9 e813ffffff      call    mscorwks!CorExitProcess+0x1c0b (79f3d5c1)
      79f92013 ffd6            call    esi
      77e64826 ff5508          call    dword ptr [ebp+8]
      In EnfieldSMSService__PID__1764__Date__01_21_2011__Time_09_34_31AM__554__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.
      dmp the assembly instruction at 0x00bb29d1 which does not correspond to any
      known native module in the process has caused an access violation exception
      (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000008 on thread 10
```

Comment: Is that all the information we get? "A Windows Service. It crashes." It crashes because it's throwing an exception. Fix whatever in your code is causing that exception, and it will stop crashing. Easy. If you want *us* to fix it, we'll need to see some source code.

Comment: We have used try-catch for any kind of exception. But the final log does not shows any exception. Can you tell me the kind of exception you noticed? Moreover Service is not crashed every time it runs. It crashes twice a day. The Event log shows : Description:
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A097706) (80131506)

Comment: See the following sring in the output you provided: has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005)